# Combine [fuseesb] and [jbossfuse]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The tags [jbossfuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbossfuse) and [fuseesb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuseesb) link to the same thing, so shouldn't they be combined? There is a synonym suggestion already in place, but no votes for it.

Suggestion: keep [jbossfuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbossfuse) as the main tag since it describes the platform better, change [fuseesb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuseesb) to be a synonym for it and retag all to [jbossfuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbossfuse).

Comment: Link to synonym page:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jbossfuse/synonyms